# Known Plain Text Attack DES-OFB on Crack.sh

Tags: encryption, des, brute-force-attack, known-plaintext-attack, ofb

I am trying to do a known plaintext attack on DES-OFB through crack.sh. I have been having trouble lately. I keep getting blank text file back with no keys returned. Does anybody know if DES-OFB is supported by Crack.sh? I tried contacting them but did not get a response. Here is what I have last submitted.

```
$ ./des_kpt.py parse -p 6c42e85de2e82693 -m fffffffffffffff -c 57ef7750e24ab08f

                 PT = 6c42e85de2e82693
                  M = ffffffffffffffff
                 CT = 57ef7750e24ab08f
                  E = 0
crack.sh Submission = $98$bELoXeLoJpP////////1fvd1DiSrCP
```

I am not sure what exactly the mask dose either. I set it to all F's. Here is the key if it helps. There is 3 due to what DES_KPT spits back out when I run a decrypt command, which also does not produce correct PT. `345E207C6D2FE679` `34bc83e6c5f9bc` `345e207c6c2ee678`

Any help or other tools is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE. Sorry, this is off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) per our rules against questions consisting largely of ciphertext/values, and questions on using tools. The question will get closed unless it moves to the crypto methods to solve such problems, their hardness…

Comment: Does the command support one of: `-h`, `--help`, `-help`, or `-?` options? The command is a shell script, maybe you can analyse the script yourself to figure out what options are needed.